# Have to press submit button twice in order to continue

Tags: php, html, cakephp

On my webpage, I have records that users can edit. When they edit. They hit the 'edit' button next to an associated record, which brings them to the edit page. Here they can edit the different fields, then hit the "SUBMIT" button to submit the edited post. They hit Submit. Nothing happens. They hit Submit again, THEN the changes are saved and they are redirected back to the index. This happens for every single post.

Here is my controller for the edit view.

```
    function edit ($id = NULL) {
    $this->loadModel('RecordDrugUnit');
    $this->loadModel('Drug');
    $this->loadModel('Unit');
    $this->loadModel('Route');

    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $record=$this->RecordDrugUnit->findByrecordId($id);
    if(!$record) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
    /*----
    * Divide dose by
    * associated conversion
    -----*/
    $record['RecordDrugUnit']['dose'] = $record['RecordDrugUnit']['dose'] / $record['Unit']['conversion'];
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['Record']['id'] = $id;
        $this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['record_id'] = $id;
        $this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['id'] = $record['RecordDrugUnit']['id'];
        $this->request->data['Record']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        /*----
        * Multiply dose by
        * associated conversion
        -----*/
        $conv_val = $this->Unit->find('first',
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'id' => $this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['unit_id']),
            'fields' => array('conversion')
            ));
        $this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['dose'] = (float)$this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['dose'] * (float)$conv_val['Unit']['conversion'];
        if ($this->RecordDrugUnit->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array('deep' => TRUE))) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your log has been updated.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to update your post.');
        }
    }

    if(!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $record;
    }


}
```

**And the view**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-m-dd' });
        });
    </script>

    <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Record'); ?>
        <header id='topHead'>
            <div class="frame headWrap">
                <div class="bit-2">
                    <div class ='padding background_color'>
                        <?php
                            echo $this->Form->input('Record.dose_date', array('placeholder' => 'Date of Dose', 'label' => false,'type' => 'text','id' =>'datepicker'));    
                            echo $this->Form->input('RecordDrugUnit.drug_id', array('placeholder' => 'Substance', 'options'=>$drugList,'label' => false,'type' => 'select')); 
                            echo $this->Form->input('RecordDrugUnit.dose', array('placeholder' => 'Dose', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'colLarge left')); 
                            echo $this->Form->input('RecordDrugUnit.unit_id', array('placeholder'=>'Unit', 'options'=>$unitList, 'label' => false,'type'=>'select', 'class' => 'colSmall right')); 
                            echo $this->Form->submit('EDIT', array('class' => 'button')); 
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bit-2">
                    <div class ='padding background_color'>
                        <span class='smallSuper'>these fields are optional</span>
                        <br>
                        <span class='smallx colSmall left'>ROA: </span>
                        <?php
                            echo $this->Form->input('RecordDrugUnit.route_id', array('placeholder'=>'Unit', 'options'=>$routeList, 'label' => false,'type'=>'select', 'class' => 'colLarge right'));
                            echo $this->Form->input('Record.title', array('placeholder' => 'Title', 'label' => false,'type' => 'text'));
                            echo $this->Form->input('Record.report', array('placeholder' => 'Your Report','label' => false,'type' => 'textarea')); 
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Comment: When you say 'nothing happens', does the form get submitted but the changes aren't saved and  you aren't redirected? Or does literally 'nothing' happen - ie, you click submit and the browser doesn't even contact the server at all?

Comment: I just checked. Here's what happens exactly. I open up the edit page, I type in something new for a field, then hit edit. The page looks like it QUICKLY refreshes, and that's it. It happens in a blink. I go check the database, and the field is still not changed. I hit edit for the second time, and I get redirected to the main page. Then I check the database and this time it did get changed.

Comment: OK, so you'll need to start debugging step by step. If you aren't able to step through code (with something like MacGDBP) then start by putting something like echo "got here"; after your line: if($this->request->is('post')) {

Comment: sorry, echo "got here"; die;

Comment: and then see if you get your 'got here' message on the first submit.

Comment: Just tried that. Put echo "here"; die; right after the line you suggested. Same thing. Submit. Nothing. Submit. "here"

Comment: hmm. I've got no idea what could be happening. post your view code. Do you have any javascript that might be involved? Try disabling javascript and see if you get the same result.

Comment: I disabled javascript in chrome, tried again, same thing. I edited the OP with the VIEW code.

Comment: hmm, I've got no idea. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, thank you anyways for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this problem.

The error was that my edit controller was sending a put request, and my code only checked for a post request.

Change line

```
if($this->request->is('post')) {
```

to

```
if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
```